# Is it appropriate to return a 401 HTTP Status Code without checking the database, when a user tries to login?

Tags: database, http, credentials, http-status-code-401

Some applications have validation rules for sign up such as

> Password must have at least 8 characters with one number, a special character.....

> Your username cannot be longer than 15 characters

If, for instance, an application has a username/email field and password field for login, and the user does not conform to the application's validation rules, is it ok to return a `401` HTTP status code, without checking the database to see if the credentials match?

The way I see it, the major positive is that you won't be making unnecessary database checks since you know the data cannot be valid anyway. However, this still feels wrong to me, almost as if there's a vulnerability ( I can't quite place my finger on any) or some rule is being violated.

Another possible issue with returning a 401 without making database calls could be if the application's validation rules change, then a username/password that was once invalid could become valid. However, it's nothing some unit tests cannot help detect.

With all that being said, is it appropriate to return a 401 HTTP Status Code without checking the database, when a user tries to login?

Comment: *My thought:* You validate the constraints when you create/update the user, not when you log in. --- My next thought is that my thoughts are my opinions, and asking for opinions is off-topic for Stack Overflow, so I'm voting to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the HTTP's protocol point, it absolutely does not matter *why* a password is incorrect. A server can do what ever works best for checking.